# Jquery Keyup in Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, keyup

I created a table, sum columns and rows. The problem I have is:

When I click the "+" button, I can sum the rows but I have a Problem with the columns.
I think it's a problem with KeyUp, but I don't know.

This is the code that sum Columns:

```
$('#sum_table tr:not(.totalCol) input:text').bind('keyup change', function() {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table');
    var total = 0;
    var thisNumber = $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)/)[1];

    $table.find('tr:not(.totalCol) .sum'+thisNumber).each(function() {
        total += parseInt(this.value);
    });

    $table.find('.totalCol td:nth-child('+thisNumber+')').html(total);
});
```

Code that increment rows and columns:

```
$("#tabla").click(function () {
        $("tr").find("td:last").before('<td><input type="text" value="0"></td>');
        var linea = $('tr:first').html();
        $('tr:last').before('<tr>'+linea+'</tr>');
        $('tr').last().find("td").last.html('<td>hola</td>');
    });
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwzY/)

Comment: your problem is not clear

Comment: @AnoopJoshi what did you mean?

Comment: can you explain more about the problem? what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: you want the row and column to increase by 1 , each time '+' button is clicked  and also show the count of the available rows and columns , right ?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Well, Im trying to sum rows and columns, and when I click on Button "+" increment, columns and rows. I can introduce in the new input text values an it will sum it again like sum it on default.

Comment: @dreamweiver Yes exactly, sorry for my bad explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the `+` button click in your fiddle

```
$("#tabla").click(function () {
   $("#sum_table tr:last-child").before('<tr><td><input type="text" value="0"></td><td><input type="text" value="0"></td><td><input type="text" value="0"></td><td class="total"> 0 </td></tr >');

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwzY/4/)

**Edit**
You need to use `on` delegate for newly created textbox keyup event,

```
$(document).on('keyup change', '#sum_table tr:not(.totalCol) input:text', function () {
       var $table = $(this).closest('table');
       var total = 0;
       var thisNumber = $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)/)[1];

       $table.find('tr:not(.totalCol) .sum' + thisNumber).each(function () {
           total += parseInt(this.value);
       });

       $table.find('.totalCol td:nth-child(' + thisNumber + ')').html(total);
   });
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwzY/6/)

**Edit**

```
$("#tabla").click(function () {

    $("#sum_table tr:last-child").before("<tr>" + $("#sum_table tr:eq(0)").html() + "</tr>");
    $("tr:not(:last-child)").each(function () {
        var classname = $(this).find("td:last-child").index() + 1;
        $(this).find("td:last-child").before('<td><input class="sum' + classname + '" type="text" value="0"></td>');
    });
    $("#sum_table tr:last-child").append("<td>0</td>");


});
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VwzY/10/)

Comment: Yes, But when I put a value in the new input text It have to sum with the old ones.And have to increment columns when I click "+" Button too.

Comment: That is!, Now the last thing that I need is to increment column too when I click "+".